# Recommended size of icon for Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This page explain 19*19 and 38*38.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#icon

But this page explain 16*16 and 48*48, 128*128.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons.html

Which is correct?

Comment: I'm sorry.I marked it now.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Both are correct ! They are for different sections/features:

The former refers to the browser-action icon (displayed on the top-right corner of your browser-window, next to the address bar). It is only displayed if your extension registers a browser-action.

The latter refers to icons used throughout the extension and browser, as is explained quite clearly in the link you provide:
<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> One or more icons that represent the extension, app, or theme. You should always provide a **128x128 icon; it's used during installation and by the Chrome Web Store**. Extensions should also provide a **48x48 icon, which is used in the extensions management page** (chrome://extensions). You can also specify a **16x16 icon to be used as the favicon** for an extension's pages. The 16x16 icon is also displayed in the experimental extension infobar feature.

---

BTW, that second link mentions `icon` as the property name, which was replaced in **Manifest v2** by `default_icon`.
<sub>(**["Migration to Manifest v2" guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#api-checklist)**)</sub>

Comment: did the spec change in this short period of time? i dont see 19 or 38 mentioned at all in the doc links provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2860966/hucuhy.

Comment: It is not impossible. 5.5 years is not a short period of time :D

Answer (score 33):

To elaborate on ExpertSystem's answer, here is an example manifest excerpt with all of the image sizes:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon19.png",
      "38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "images/icon16.png",
           "48": "images/icon48.png",
          "128": "images/icon128.png" }, ...
```

Notice how the 19/38 icons are for the browser action, and the 16/48/128 are at the icons level.

I think it is best therefore to create the image as a vector graphic (e.g. svg file) and then save to a bitmap (e.g. png file) for each of the sizes.

Answer (score 29):

---

**2020 Update:**

I was researching this recently.  Here is what I found:
These sizes seem to cover most scenarios: 16, 24, 32, 48, 128
These sizes seem to be outdated: 19, 38

---

**Icons - Recommended Sizes:**

16, 24, 32, 48, 128.

```
Size:   Manifest - Icons:   chrome.browserAction:

16      Yes                 Yes
24      No                  Yes
32      Yes                 Yes
48      Yes                 No
128     Yes                 No
```

- Manifest - Icons: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons
- chrome.browserAction: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

---

**Icons - Outdated Sizes:**

19, 38.

```
Size:   Manifest - Icons:   chrome.browserAction:

19      No                  Outdated
38      No                  Outdated
```

- chrome.browserAction: https://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/browserAction.html

---

Answer (score 3):

For browser action, we just need a 16x16 icon now, as

> [The browser action icons in Chrome are 16 dips (`device-independent pixels`) wide and high.](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/icons)